# How to programmatically navigate in a FlipView with swipe animations

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

The Windows Dev Center states regarding the `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation` property:

> The XAML FlipView control supports three modes of navigation; touch-based, button-based and programmatic. When a user navigates by touch, the FlipView items scroll smoothly into view. When you set this property to true, the same navigation animation occurs whether the navigation is touch-based, button-based and programmatic.

I'm currently navigating from my page's code behind by assigning the `SelectedItem` property of the FlipView:

```
FlipView.SelectedItem = FlipView.Items.Last();
```

However, the swipe animation does not show. How can I enable it?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but my experience is that only the smooth navigation animation occurs when you select the item in the list 'next' to the selecteditem.

Comment: I already tried that. How do you navigate to the next item?

Comment: In my case I have a list of thumbnails showing al the items and when i select the thumbnail next to the current selecteditem it navigating with the animation, if I select one further than the selecteditem it just comes to the screen without any animation.

Comment: Could you share your code that triggers the navigation?

Comment: var index = dataContext.ProductDetails.Media.IndexOf(media);
ImageFlipView.SelectedIndex = index;

Comment: It doesn't navigate when I change SelectedIndex... it's really weird. I don't make use of data binding, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Do you have a solution to share?

Comment: Unfortunately not... But I just noticed that when I set `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation` to false, it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meanwhile, I was able to solve this problem. I have a button that triggers the navigation to the next FlipViewItem. This button however was placed in a FlipViewItem.

With my setup (touch device), nothing happend. Then I tried clicking the button with the mouse and it worked. After I disabled `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation`, it also worked using touch input. In my tests, I placed the button outside of the FlipView and it did work using animations.

Here's the problem: When tapping the button, the navigation animation tries to start (`SelectedIndex` is set correctly), but stopped because the user blocks the animation by still touching the button. So, the navigation is cancelled and `SelectionChanged` reports the current page.

The solution is to set `ManipulationMode` of the Button to `All`. After that, you can't flip the FlipViewItem when touching the button, but the animation executes and it works like charm.

Comment: Just FYI and everybody who might come across this: This still applies for Windows 10 Universal apps.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem in a different way. As Chliebel said, it is because your finger is still touching the control, so flipview cannot animate. So I gave a small break after before navigating. By the time user would have released the finger and it works !!!

```
        await Task.Delay(100);
        flipView.SelectedIndex += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, ChristiaanV's answer has helped:

> Animation only occurs when you navigate to the previous or next item
>   in the FlipView.

So I've set up a while loop to set the selected index to the previous / next one until I reach the desired page.

### Example Code:

If you'd like to reach the first page:

```
while(flipView.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    flipView.SetValue(FlipView.SelectedIndexProperty, flipView.SelectedIndex - 1);
}
```

Comment: well, this would trigger back animation, so it wouldn't be desired behaviour. but it's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact solution I found, similar to Bhawk1990's:

```
//nb is the index you wish to get to.

if (nb > flipview.SelectedIndex)
    while (flipview.SelectedIndex != nb)
        flipview.SelectedIndex++;
else if (nb < flipview.SelectedIndex)
    while (flipview.SelectedIndex != nb)
        flipview.SelectedIndex--;
```

Answer (score -2):

I spent a couple of days figuring out why touch animation does not work when I programmatically change FlipView selected item when `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="True"`.

I found a setting which controls animation machine wide. Somehow this setting was disabled:

```
Settings->Visual options->Play animations in Windows
```