# Why UWP Flipview doesn't flip to second item?

Tags: c#, synchronization, uwp-xaml, issue-tracking, flipview

I have a control to manage a FlipView (`flipView`) and I want synchronize SelectedIndex with a ListBox (`subMenuList`) to navigate between my contents. And because product owners have wonderfull requirements, I have another ListBox (`shortcutList`) in a control for the first item of the FlipView which is also binded to SelectedIndex of the FlipView.

*Warning : some items of the lists are collapsed to simulate shortcuts to Flipview contents.*

Those controls are perfectly synchronized together **but** the second item of FlipView :

- **Using mouse**: on the first click, I can go to page 1 and when I flip back to `shortcutList`, I can not go to page 1 but I can go anywhere else. And then, when I flip back again to `shortcutList`, I can go to page 1 again and so on !
- **Using touch**: I can tap go to page 1 as long as I want, I never reach my first page but I can go anywhere else.

I extract the specific part of my project to reproduce the use case on [Github](https://github.com/agentsmith75002/SynchronizedSelectedIndex), that way everyone can understand what I mean.

I hope someone can tell me **why UWP Flipview doesn't flip to second item** ? And thanks to try to help me to find an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the item is already in selected state, so you cannot select it again - at least selecting it does not do anything as there is no selection changed event and hence the `SelectedIndex` binding doesn't propagate any changes. To prove it - the same thing happens if you jump to page 4, flip back to first page and click page 4 again.

How to solve this? I think you will have to use code. This XAML solution although almost works is quite fragile. The easiest solution would be to replace the `ListBox` in `FlipContent0Control` with three simple buttons and in their `Click` handlers navigate to the appropriate page. For an even better approach you should try to change the app to use MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I also commited a dirty fix on [Github](https://github.com/agentsmith75002/SynchronizedSelectedIndex) using directions of [Martin Zikmund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732221/martin-zikmund)

> How to solve this? I think you will have to use code. This XAML
>   solution although almost works is quite fragile. The easiest solution
>   would be to replace the ListBox in FlipContent0Control with three
>   simple buttons and in their Click handlers navigate to the appropriate
>   page.

and a tip from [Jawahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693776/jawahar)

> it is because your finger is still touching the control, so flipview
>   cannot animate. So I gave a small break after before navigating. By
>   the time user would have released the finger and it works !!!

in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305268/how-to-programmatically-navigate-in-a-flipview-with-swipe-animations).
So, three steps to resolve :

1. Replace `SelectedIndex` in `FlipContent0Control` with `Tapped` event on each `ListBoxItem` inner canvas.
2. Provide a event on tap to raise the target index to select in the `FlipView`.
3. Add a `Task.Delay(100)` in the method handler of event `TargetedIndexChanged`